# Making discord bot account for different channel types

Tags: python, discord, bots, cross-server

I am attempting to make a discord bot with python that reads a channel post in one server; if they contain a video embedded link, then the bot automatically sends that message to another channel in a difference server.

However, the problem that I'm currently attempting to solve is how to go about changing the above code to account for difference channel types; i.e. original server is a text channel and the new server channel is a forum type.

Any ideas about how I could go about doing that?

Thank you!

-Jay

This is what I have so far:

```
    import discord
    client = discord.Client()
    channel1id = ORIGINALCHANNELIDHERE
    channel2id = NEWCHANNELIDHERE

    @bot.event
        async def on_ready():
            print("Bot is ready")
    
    @bot.event
        async def on_message(message):
            if message.channel.id == channel1id:
                if message.embeds:
                    for embed in message.embeds:
                        if embed.type == "video":
                            channeltosend = client.get_channel(channel2id)
                            await channeltosend.send(message.content, embed=message.embeds[0])
                            break; 
        
        
    client.run("TOKEN")
```